# D3: uncaught exception: Object

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to get some data from a `.csv` file using `d3.queue()` method. This is my code for it:

```js
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "./data/Adult Literacy/API_SE.ADT.LITR.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_612567.csv")
    .defer(d3.csv, "./data/GPD Growth/API_NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG_DS2_en_csv_v2_612605.csv")
    .await(function(error, lit, gpd) {
        if (error) throw error

        console.log(lit)
    })
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```sh
.
├── app.js
├── data
│   ├── Adult Literacy
│   │   ├── API_SE.ADT.LITR.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_612567.csv
│   │   ├── Metadata_Country_API_SE.ADT.LITR.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_612567.csv
│   │   └── Metadata_Indicator_API_SE.ADT.LITR.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_612567.csv
│   └── GPD Growth
│       ├── API_NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG_DS2_en_csv_v2_612605.csv
│       ├── Metadata_Country_API_NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG_DS2_en_csv_v2_612605.csv
│       └── Metadata_Indicator_API_NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG_DS2_en_csv_v2_612605.csv
├── index.html
└── style.css
```

And I'm running a local http-server to do all this stuff. Unfortunately, the only thing I'm getting is this error message: `uncaught exception: Object`. This message is not helping me to deal with the error, I wish to know what could I do to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've managed to solve this error. The problem was in my index.html file, apparently d3.queue() function is not available in d3.v5, so I need to be using an early version like d3.v4. Just after I switch those scripts, my code worked just fine